# Why can I use deleted "deliver" method on ActionMailer::MessageDelivery in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-6

```rb
irb(main)> Rails.version
=> "6.0.3.3"

irb(main)> AwesomeNotifier.send_recommend_notification(self).method(:deliver).owner
AwesomeNotifier#send_recommend_notification: processed outbound mail in 0.2ms
=> ActionMailer::MessageDelivery

irb(main)> AwesomeNotifier::MessageDelivery.instance_methods(false)
=> [:deliver_later!, :deliver_later, :deliver_now!, :deliver_now, :message, :processed?, :__setobj__, :__getobj__]
```

It looks there is no `deliver` method in `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery`
Because it deleted on 5.0 [commit here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/755dcd0691f74079c24196135f89b917062b0715)
But it works somehow.

Where comes from this `deliver` ??
I should use `deliver_later` or `deliver_now` but wanna make it clear what this `deliver` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AwesomeNotifier::MessageDelivery` is a delegator object - that is, it is a wrapper around another object; while it provides its own methods, if you call a method on it that isn't explicitly defined on it, the message gets passed to the object it's wrapping.

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html):

> The ActionMailer::MessageDelivery class is used by ActionMailer::Base when creating a new mailer. MessageDelivery is a wrapper (Delegator subclass) around a lazy created Mail::Message.

While `MessageDelivery` defines `deliver_later` and `deliver_now`, calling `deliver` will actually place the call on an instance of `Mail::Message`. The implementation for that is [here](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/message.rb#L250-L259).

I suspect that the delegator pattern is kept on this instance for historical reasons, and there may be Rails code that depends on some `Mail::Message` methods being available on `MessageDelivery`. But it can cause confusion as to which methods `MessageDelivery` actually responds to and what its expected behaviour might be.

In your own code, if you were to ever *really* need access to the message directly, it might be clearer if you use MessageDelivery's [`#message`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-message) method to explicitly reference the message.

Comment: Thank you for your appropriate answering.
I've become clear about how this methods comes from.
And I learned delegator pattern, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Could I ask you to mark this answer as accepted? Thanks!